# LINQ GroupBy extremely slow

Tags: c#, linq, mono

The following code takes 5 minutes to run on 100,000 rows. That seems crazy to me. What am I doing wrong?

```
        var query =
            from foo in fooStuff.AsEnumerable()
            group foo by foo.Field<Int64>("FooID") into g
            select new
            {
                    FooID = g.Key,
                    FooTier = g.Min(foo => foo.Field<int>("Tier"))
            };
```

Note: On Mono.

Comment: I use query.CopyToDataTable() after that.

Comment: What is fooStuff? Is it a deferred query?  If you do fooStuff.ToList() before this line of code, does that ToList take 5 minutes?

Comment: What's in `.Field<>`?  For sufficiently slow implementations, 5 minutes is not hard to believe.

Comment: (particularly if it contains any reflection)

Comment: You're the only guy here who can run a profiler over the code. What does your profile run say is the bottleneck?

Comment: fooStuff is a DataTable. I am using Mono, so there is no profiler at this time.

Answer (score 5):

You are materializing all the entities when you call AsEnumerable(), so your grouping is being done in memory. Try removing that part so that the grouping is done at the database level:

```
var query =
        from foo in fooStuff
        group foo by foo.FooID into g
        select new
        {
                FooID = g.Key,
                FooTier = g.Min(foo => foo.Tier)
        };
```

Comment: If (as stated in the comments) fooStuff is a dataTable, does that not mean you need AsEnumerable()?

Comment: DataTables require AsEnumerable(). We don't want to access the database to do this. Furthermore, why would doing it "at the database level" increase speed? Memory should be faster, and indeed, that is the point.

Comment: Alfonso's answer would apply if fooStuff was a SQL table, as using AsEnumerable() could slow this down drastically as it would doing a select * from foostuff which returns the whole table, whereas without it, the generated sql would be something like select fooid, Min(tier) as footier from foostuff group by fooid.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a direct comparision and isn't on Mono, but I have some code which does something similar with a 6MB xml file which I read into a DataSet and it has 30,000 rows and takes 0.5 seconds, so I don't think it is the groupby itself that causes the problem.

To diagnose further, I would suggest

- Testing how long it takes to read the information into a list, ie

  ```
  var fooList = fooStuff.AsEnumerable().ToList();
  ```
- Testing how long it takes if you change the query to use fooList instead of fooStuff
- Testing how long it takes if you remove FooTier = g.Min(foo => foo.Tier) from the select
- Separate the .Field<> reflection from the groupby and time each section, ie first read the information from the datatable into a list , eg

  ```
  var list2 =
  (from foo in fooStuff.AsEnumerable()
  select new { 
      FooID = foo.Field<Int64>("FooID") 
      Tier  = foo.Field<int>("Tier")
  }).ToList();
  ```

  Then you can query this list

  ```
  var query =
  from foo in list2
  group foo by foo.FooID into g
  select new
  {
          FooID = g.Key,
          FooTier = g.Min(foo => foo.Tier)
  };
  var results = query.ToList();
  ```

If this query is slow, it would suggest that there is something wrong with mono's implementation of GroupBy. You might be able to verify that by using something like this

```
    public static Dictionary<TKey, List<TSrc>> TestGroupBy<TSrc, TKey>
     (this IEnumerable<TSrc> src, Func<TSrc,TKey> groupFunc)
    {
        var dict= new Dictionary<TKey, List<TSrc>>();

        foreach (TSrc s in src)
        {
            TKey key = groupFunc(s);
            List<TSrc> list ;

            if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out list))
            {
                list = new List<TSrc>();
                dict.Add(key, list);
            }       
            list.Add(s);        
            }

        return dict;
}
```

And to use it

```
  var results = list2.TestGroupBy(r=>r.FooID)
      .Select(r=>  new { FooID = r.Key, FooTier = r.Value.Min(r1=>r1.Tier)} );
```

Note, this is not meant as a replacement for groupby and does not cope with null keys but should be enough to determine if their is a problem with groupby (assuming mono's implementation of Dictionary and List are ok).

Comment: Done all of that. Still 5 minutes.

Comment: Are you saying that each routine, including both sections of the last routine, took the same time?

Comment: Just the group by part takes 5 minutes.

Comment: This looks like a mono issue. I have amended my answer to provide a method which might confirm that by avoiding the groupby